# Upper bound on the mutual information for a mixture distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory

Assume we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. Suppose further that $X$ is generated from a mixture distribution $P$ with $n$ components $P_i$ with corresponding weights $w_1,\dots,w_n$. Is it the case that the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ is bounded above by the weighted sum of the mutual information between $Y$ and each of the mixture components of $X$? That is, is it the case that $I(X,Y) = D_{KL}(P||Q)\leq \sum_{i}w_{i}D_{KL}(P_i||Q)$?

Comment: The way you've written things is ripe for confusion: it is true that $I(X;Y)$ is a KL divergence, but specifically this is $D(P_{XY}\|P_X \circ P_Y)$. What precisely do you mean by $P$ and $Q$ in the expression you wrote? Are you assuming that $P_X \circ P_Y$ remains constant, but the $P_{XY}$ gets disintegrated into mixture components? In this case the inequality you wrote is true (due to convexity of KL divergence), but this is not really a meaningful way to consider this since things like $D((P_{XY})_i \|P_X\circ P_Y)$ are not mutual informations. One situation that people (contd.)

Comment: often consider is when the channel $P_{Y|X}$ is held constant, but the distribution $P_X$ is varied. In this setting, $D(P_{XY}\|P_X\circ P_Y)$ turns out to be a *concave* function of $P_X$, and the opposite inequality holds. I'd suggest you carefully check how you intend to formulate your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be the indicator variable of the mixture. Assume $Z$ (but not $P_i$) is independent of $Y$.

Then $H(X) = H(X|Z) + H(Z) - H(Z|X)= \sum w_i H(P_i) + h(w) - H(Z|X)$

And $$I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)=\sum w_i \, H(P_i) - H(Z|X) - \sum w_i\, H(P_i|Y) + H(Z|X,Y)\\
= \sum w_i \,I(P_i,Y) - I(Z,Y|X) \le \sum w_i \,I(P_i,Y)$$

Then, yes, the conjecture is true. But subject to the above (non trivial) assumption: that $Y$ is not related to the mixing.

Counter example, if the assumption does not hold: suppose the components don't overlap (hence $H(Z|X)=0$), and take $Y=Z$ (hence $H(Z|Y)=0$). Then

$$I(X;Y)=\sum w_i \,I(P_i,Y) +H(Z)$$